# How to remove extra spaces in between with Grid in CSS

Tags: css

How can i remove the white spaces and fit all the content close to each other ?

This is what I have now, but im stuck on remove the white spaces.. i just need them to be close to each other...

```
.wrapper {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 2fr 30vw;
            grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, fit-content));
            height: fit-content;
            list-style: none;
            grid-gap: 0;
        }

        .card {
            height: fit-content !important;
            border: 2px solid red !important;
    }
```

[image]